Curve modifier weird results
I've been trying to attach an already ring-shaped object to a circular curve. But despite playing with the deform axis, origins, scales, rotations... I can't figure out why my object is deformed in these pinched-bean ways, as a cylinder would cast an anamorphosis.
I guess I'm missing something here.
Blend file attached
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DXrhSUpcemUDqCWY2yU36wIcTQAtcFl9/view?usp=sharing
Any help is welcome


I'm not sure what you're trying to do, if you give a Curve modifier to a long flat subdivided rectangle, this rectangle will bend along the curve, but if you give a Curve modifier to a circular shape, this shape will deform to a weird bean shape that won't be a circle

I thought this method would allow me to link the ring shape to the circular curve so that when the curve is dynamically deformed the mesh would also. I tried doing that via mesh deform but can’t since the mesh’s Z rotation should be also driven by external var. any other idea?

If you give a Curve modifier to a long flat subdivided rectangle, this rectangle will bend along the curve, but if you give a Curve modifier to an already circular shape, this shape will deform to a weird bean shape or a ∝ shape that won't be a circle.
What you could do instead is create this segment:

Array it with an Array modifier:

Make it circular with a Curve modifier, use your curve as Curve Object:


Your problem is that you already have a deformed object that you're attempting to deform again. This is with the Curve Mod disabled:

It already aligns to that Curve perfectly.

You might have already previously applied another Curve modifier.
